# Virtualbox: compute the time the VM was in active use

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I do all my work in a VM run by Virtualbox, and I was wondering if it was possible to compute the time VMs have been in active use.

Ideally I would like to break it down by day, so I can see how much time I work in a particular VM for any given day.

PS: when I am not actively working on a VM I either shut it down or put it to sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each VM usage session generates an individual log-file (located in the logs subfolder of the VM's folder).
The date-time stamp on the log-file indicates when it was last closed.
Each line in the log-file has a time-stamp in "time since startup" of the VM. So take the last time-stamp at the end of the log and substract that from the files own time-stamp and you know when the session was started.
(Rebooting or resetting the VM is all logged in that file. Shutting down the VM completely ends the log.)

Older logs are retained too (not sure how many, you'll have to try it out or consult the VirtualBox manual).
I also don't know if 2 separate usage sessions of the same VM on 1 day end up in the same log-file or get separate files. The latter would be most logical, but I don't have any examples of that around at this time. That is easy enough to experiment with though.

Just backup the logs (multiple times a day if you do run more sessions per day than the maximum retention on the older logs) and you can work out the usage statistics from them.
Should be easy enough to script something together in python, perl, powershell or whatever other script-language you prefer to automate all that.

Comment: Thanks, I think that will do! It retains only 4 files of log (`VBox.log` to `VBox.log.3`) and I have to search for state changes inside the logs but that will be easy enough! When I pause it there are logs about `00:10:03.819985 Changing the VM state from 'RUNNING' to 'SUSPENDING'` and later `02:35:28.732122 Changing the VM state from 'RESUMING' to 'RUNNING'` so I have all the infos. It seems it creates one new log file every time I close the VM completely indeed.

Comment: I never suspend them and only  run 1 session in a VM per day, so I couldn't tell how that would like in the logs. But that looks like it is all you need indeed.

Comment: Yes I'll write a little script and check that everything is fine but from the looks of it all the info is there. I usually close my VM every one or two days, but pause it often during the day whenever I have something else to do. So I can consider that whenever the VM is active I am working, and bill accordingly.